# Easy to use JPEG to Bitmap converter for Delphi 6 that is efficient with memory usage?

Tags: delphi, directshow, jpeg, tbitmap

Is there an easy to use JPEG converter (source code) for Delphi 6 that will convert a JPEG frame in a memory buffer  to a DirectShow compatible bitmap quickly and without constant memory re-allocation?  I'm trying to avoid the default JPEG unit in conjunction with TBitmap because it allocates a new bitmap with every conversion, and has some other initialize/teardown operations involved with each operation too.

I'll be receiving JPEG frames from an RTP server that I need to convert to bitmaps and push out through the FillBuffer() call of my DirectShow filter.  Each frame will be exactly the same size and format since they are streamed from a video capture device using preset settings.  Therefore, if I could allocate the bitmap only once, and then convert each incoming JPEG frame into the existing bitmap memory area, I could avoid re-allocating a chunk of memory 25 times a second and the overhead of any other ancillary data objects Delphi involves in the conversion process used in the JPEG unit along with TBitmap.

It doesn't have to be lightning fast from a CPU usage perspective.  Just fast enough to handle a 640 x 480 JPEG frame conversion in less than 1/25 of a second (1/15 to be safe).

Comment: "Delphi 7" in the header not in sync with "Delphi 6" in the content.

Comment: Must the converter be derived from TGraphic ?

Comment: try the `TOleGraphic`. load the jpeg from stream and assign forward to bitmap. (or maybe I just didn't understand the Q...)

Comment: @menjaraz - Thanks, fixed it.  No the converter does not have to be derived from TGraphic.

Comment: @menjaraz.  Share what?  I'm looking for a jpeg decoder, not writing one.  So far it looks like I'll be going with the Synopse fast JPEG decoder: http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=8

Comment: I thought you have fixed the problem by writing a new custom class.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the memory usage but a very small JPEG-decoder with source that you can easily modify yourself is NanoJPEG: http://keyj.emphy.de/nanojpeg/

Delphi conversion here: http://www.emix8.org/static.php?page=nanoJpeg

Comment: That looks like a nice library, but there's no license information in your port, at least I didn't see one in NanoJpeg.pas or anywhere else, so it can't be used by others.  I know NanoJpeg.c has a liberal BSD style license, but your file is a derived work and licenses do not "pass through" on derived works.  You have to explicitly add one.

Comment: I've now copied the license information from NanoJpeg.c and pasted into NanoJpeg.pas. Please download it again and see if that is what you want. I've found it to be very stable. You need to change a couple of small things to make it Delphi 6 compatible though (move the private type declarations outside the class declarations, and skip the "strict" keyword), let me know if you need help with that.